# How to make these subclasses interact with each other?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, polymorphism

I have this pokemon application, which i would like to get these pokemon to "battle" I want to make the health a reference variable, which is located in private section of pokemon class. I don't know how to initialize reference variables in c++ classes. Thanks for your time in reading my post. I hope someone out there will help me.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  pokemon
//
//  Created by Frank Novello on 8/25/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Frank Novello. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
class Pokemon
{
public:
    Pokemon(){};
    ~Pokemon(){};

    void setName(string x){name = x;};
    string getName(){return name;};

    void setLevel(int x){level = x;};
    int getLevel(){return level;};

    void setHeight(int x){height = x;};
    int getHeight(){return height;};

    void setWeight(int x){weight = x;};
    int getWeight(){return weight;};

    void setHealth(int x){health = x;};
    int getHealth(){return health;};


    void displayStats()
    {
        cout << "pokemon: "      <<   name << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\tlevel: "  <<  level << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\thp: "     << health << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\theight: " << height << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\tweight: " << weight << endl;
    }

private:
    string name;
    int level;
    int height;
    int health;     //Want to make this a reference variable
    float weight;
};
//<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
class ElectricPokemon: public Pokemon
{
public:
    ElectricPokemon(){};
    ~ElectricPokemon(){};
    void attack()
    {
        cout <<"Shocked" << endl;
    }
private:
};
//<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
class WaterPokemon: public Pokemon
{
public:
    WaterPokemon(){};
    ~WaterPokemon(){};
private:
};
//<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
class FirePokemon: public Pokemon
{
public:
    FirePokemon(){};
    ~FirePokemon(){};
private:
};
//<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
class PsycicPokemon: public Pokemon
{
public:
    PsycicPokemon(){};
    ~PsycicPokemon(){};
private:
};
//<------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ElectricPokemon * pickachew = new ElectricPokemon();
    WaterPokemon * squirtle = new WaterPokemon();
    PsycicPokemon * kahdabra = new PsycicPokemon();
    FirePokemon * charmander = new FirePokemon();
    cout << "\n\t\t\t <-------------Pokedex------------->" << endl;
    bool quit = false;

    while (!quit) {

        cout << "Slect a Pokemon to view stats: "<< "\n\t\t 1-Pickachew" << "\n\t\t 2-Squirtle" <<  "\n\t\t 3-Charmander" <<  "\n\t\t 4-Kahdabra"<< endl;
        int x;
        cin >> x;

        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                pickachew -> setName("Pickachew");
                pickachew -> setLevel(1);
                pickachew -> setHealth(100);
                pickachew -> setHeight(1);
                pickachew -> setWeight(10);
                pickachew -> displayStats();
                break;
            case 2:
                squirtle -> setName("Squirtle");
                squirtle -> setLevel(1);
                squirtle -> setHealth(80);
                squirtle -> setHeight(1);
                squirtle -> setWeight(15);
                squirtle -> displayStats();
                break;
            case 3:
                charmander -> setName("Charmander");
                charmander -> setLevel(1);
                charmander -> setHealth(120);
                charmander -> setHeight(1);
                charmander -> setWeight(15);
                charmander -> displayStats();
                break;
            case 4:
                kahdabra -> setName("Kahdabra");
                kahdabra -> setLevel(60);
                kahdabra -> setHealth(800);
                kahdabra -> setHeight(6);
                kahdabra -> setWeight(150);
                kahdabra -> displayStats();
                break;
        }
        cout << "\n\n\t\t Would you like to select another Pokemon(y/n): " << endl;
        string choice;
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == "n")
        {
            quit = true;

        }else quit = false;
    }

    cout << "Program Quiting..." << endl; return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those four pointers in `main` are very unnecessary. If you do need polymorphism with them later, use a smart pointer. Anyway, why exactly do you want the health to be a reference? It can backfire very easily and there's probably no good reason for doing so.

Comment: I will look into smart pointers. I wanted to make one pokemon's attack affect another's health so i thought i needed to make health a reference variable.

Comment: @FrankNovello I'm still unable to understand *how* using a reference for `health` is going to help you (maybe you could provide an example of what you want to do?). To make to objects interact you can e.g. use a member function like `void Pokemon::attack(Pokemon&)`.

Comment: @FrankNovello I think you are misunderstanding what a "reference variable" is...  What would it reference? Every reference variable needs an actual variable to reference... Are you getting mixed up with pointers vs. refernces? Or do you mean something completely different by "reference variable"?

Answer (score 0):

Make `health` variable `protected` instead of `private`. Then you will be able to access it in every class that is derived from `Pokemon`.

Comment: ok thanks now if i wanted to run a function attack from squirt to attack pikachew how can i get it so it attacks pikachews health variable?

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote, but instead I'll just comment: that breaks encapsulation, which is bad architecture. Instead provide (protected if appropriate) getters and setters. Just because something is small now is no excuse, small things have tendency to grow... Learning is no excuse either, because you should learn proper design. A good IDE can make the pain of writing accessor methods less.

Comment: hyde can you help with my question please?

Comment: `protected` only lets you access base class members of your *own* object inside member functions. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c8fe22a5f8)

Comment: @hyde In fact, there are arguments that making those kinds of variables accessible wouldn't break encapsulation because it already is (arguably) broken. The OP already provides getters and setters w/o any additional functionality (like checks) and no restrictions. The contract essentially is *what you receive is what you stored*. That said, the *design itself* isn't the best (*tell, don't ask*).

Comment: @DyP the point of providing accessors is, you can change the code later. Exposed data member is a fixed data member, it's meaning or implementation of it can "never" be changed without breaking other code. For example, adding thread safety later is impossible.

Comment: @hyde I don't want to restart that discussion here, but if you had/wanted to change the restrictions on the setters for example, or the contract in general, it wouldn't be bad to have to think about every occurrence of an access. I think we agree that the design is flawed either way.

Comment: @DyP Fair enough, though for that purpose, I'd propose using `friend` instead of making data members protected, to make dependencies explicit, but that's an entirely different discussion.

Comment: can someone show me how to declare a reference variable in a class?

Comment: @FrankNovello To use a refernce member variable in class: `class Foo { public: Foo(int &i): intRef(i) {}; private: int & intRef; };`. But this is rather uncommon to do that, I'm pretty sure you don't actually want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can access private member functions and protected member functions from another class or object types by using the keyword `friend`. You need to include the class that contains the private member functions or protected member functions in your header file such as

```
class A {
  friend class B;
}
```

And you can also do it the other way round. Thus class B can be a friend of class A and class A can be a friend of class B.